# Using gBrowser and observerService to find a tab on startup

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create a firefox addon that will look for a certain page on startup and grab some info from it. I'm having trouble finding the page at load. Here's what I have so far:

```
var myfancyaddon = {
  onLoad: function() {
      var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
      observerService.addObserver(function restored() {
          observerService.removeObserver( restored, "sessionstore-windows-restored");
          var browser = myfancyaddon.findMySite();
          if (browser) {
              alert("tree falling in the woods"); // THIS LINE NEVER RUNS
              browser.contentWindow.addEventListener("load", function tab_loaded(){
                  browser.contentWindow.removeEventListener("load", tab_loaded(), false);
                  alert("mysite loaded!");
              }, false);
          }
      }, "sessionstore-windows-restored", false);
  },

  findMySite: function() {
      var browsers = gBrowser.browsers;
      for ( var i = 0; i < browsers.length; i++ ) {
          var browser = browsers[i];
          if (!browser.currentURI.spec) continue;
          if ( browser.currentURI.spec.match('^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/') ) return browser;
      }
      return null;
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function ff_loaded(){
    window.removeEventListener("load", ff_loaded, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myfancyaddon.onLoad();
},false);
```

after some investigation it seems the currentURI.spec is "about:blank" for a short time before it becomes mysite.com. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering first and then adding the load listener, you could use `gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myfunction, false);` to listen for page loads on all tab documents and then only run your code based on the url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

Answer (score 0):

The `"sessionstore-windows-restored"` notification is sent when the tabs from the previous session have been restored and the loading in these tabs has been started (sometimes: "Don't load tabs until selected" option means that the load isn't even started in the background tabs). But the location of these tabs is still `about:blank` until the server is contacted because the address loaded might redirect or the server might be unreachable (meaning an internal redirect to `about:neterror`). Firefox only changes browser location when content is definitely being served from the new location.

It should be indeed better to [intercept page loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) rather than waiting for session restore.